# How to scroll down to a component on the same page

Tags: angular

I have multiple components on the same page with each having a min-height of 100vh. On top there is a navbar.So, i want to scroll down to a particular component when the navbar item is clicked. How to do that? I tried using ViewPortScroller in the main component which contains all these components, but it is not working.

```
<app-navbar (currentCategorySelected)="scrollTo($event)" class="navbar"></app-navbar>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <app-about-me id="about"></app-about-me>
    <app-skills #skills></app-skills>
    <app-experience-section></app-experience-section>
</div>
```

```
scrollTo(id) {
    this.viewPortScroller.scrollToAnchor(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'scrollIntoView' method like so:

**HTML**

```
<app-navbar (click)="scrollTo(#id)" class="navbar"></app-navbar>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <app-about-me id="about"></app-about-me>
    <app-skills #skills></app-skills>
    <app-experience-section></app-experience-section>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
scrollTo(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

With this method you need a seperat elemtn with an on click event handler for each component you want to scroll to.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But can you tell me why viewPortScroller wasn't working?